# Convert decimal to percentage value

Tags: decimal-number, percentage

How can I convert a given decimal into the respective percentage value with a certain amount of positions q after the comma? The percentage should be rounded with respect to q+1.

For example, I am looking for something like

> \percentage[position after the comma]{given decimal}

that produces:

```
\percentage[positions-after-comma = 2]{0.12123456}: 12.12% 
\percentage[positions-after-comma = 4]{0.12123456}: 12.1235%
\percentage[positions-after-comma = 4]{2.12123456}: 212.1235%
\percentage[positions-after-comma = 1]{0.6789}: 67.9%
\percentage[positions-after-comma = 5]{0.6789}: 67.89000%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\percentage[2][round-precision = 2]{% default precision: 2
    \SI[round-mode = places,
        scientific-notation = fixed, fixed-exponent = 0,
        output-decimal-marker={.}, #1]{#2e2}{\percent}%
}

\begin{document}

    \percentage{0.123456} % -> 12.35 %
    \percentage[round-precision = 3]{0.123456} % -> 12.345 %

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your values looks wrong. But beside this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\l_bjprim_round_int
\keys_define:nn {bjprim}
{
 positions-after-comma .int_set:N = \l_bjprim_round_int
}

\NewDocumentCommand\percentage { O{} m }
{
 \keys_set:nn {bjprim}{positions-after-comma=2,#1}
 \fpeval{round(#2*100,\l_bjprim_round_int)}\%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}


\percentage[positions-after-comma = 2]{0.123456}: 12.12%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 4]{0.123456}: 12.1235%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 4]{2.123456}: 212.1235%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 1]{0.6789}: 67.9%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 5]{0.6789}: 67.89000%

\end{document}
```

If you really want to fill up with zeros you could round with siunitx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp,xparse,siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N\l_bjprim_round_int
\keys_define:nn {bjprim}
{
 positions-after-comma .int_set:N = \l_bjprim_round_int
}

\NewDocumentCommand\percentage { O{} m }
{
 \keys_set:nn {bjprim}{positions-after-comma=2,#1}
 \num[round-mode = places,round-precision=\l_bjprim_round_int]{\fpeval{#2*100}}\%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}


\percentage[positions-after-comma = 2]{0.123456}: 12.12%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 4]{0.123456}: 12.1235%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 4]{2.123456}: 212.1235%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 1]{0.6789}: 67.9%

\percentage[positions-after-comma = 5]{0.6789}: 67.89000%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This way the optional argument is actually mandatory.

Comment: I am struggling to get your code running. It says: "File `xfp.sty' not found." I am working with Overleaf, can it be that this package is not supported?

Comment: That's not what I meant; if you use `\percentage{<number>}`, the previous value is used, which may or may not be desired.

Comment: @egreg ? I'm setting it to 2 as a default, and this is the value I get when I use the command without optional argument.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I see, now.

Comment: You can remove xfp and replace \fpeval by `\fp_eval:n`.